# Why is my choropleth map in python empty?

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

So I am trying to learn to plot choropleth maps. I used a sample dataset but it comes out empty. Please could you look at it and tell me what is wrong because I have crosschecked the syntax and do not understand why it does not show my data. I have included the dataset head and the code I wrote as seen below:
[image: screenshot of datahead]

```
datia = dict(type = 'choropleth',
            locations = df['Names'],
            locationmode = 'USA-states',
            colorscale= 'Portland',
            text= df['Names'],
            z=df['2010-11'],
            colorbar = {'title':'Vaccine Coverage in percentage'})
layout = dict(title = 'Vaccine Coverage in percentage',
              geo = {'scope':'usa'})
choromap = go.Figure(data = [datia],layout = layout)
iplot(choromap, validate=False)
```

[image: myemptymap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give STATE Abbreviations(DC,AL,...) instead of Names.
I faced the same issue. It worked after changing that.
You can use the following code to convert names to abbreviations

```
def convert_state_name(name):
    cd=str(name)
    us_state_abbrev = {
    "Alabama":"AL"
    "Alaska":"AK"
    "Arizona":"AZ"
    "Arkansas":"AR"
    "California":"CA"
    "Colorado":"CO"
    "Connecticut":"CT"
    "Delaware":"DE"
    "Washington DC":"DC"
    "Florida":"FL"
    "Georgia":"GA"
    "Hawaii":"HI"
    "Idaho":"ID"
    "Illinois":"IL"
    "Indiana":"IN"
    "Iowa":"IA"
    "Kansas":"KS"
    "Kentucky":"KY"
    "Louisiana":"LA"
    "Maine":"ME"
    "Maryland":"MD"
    "Massachusetts":"MA"
    "Michigan":"MI"
    "Minnesota":"MN"
    "Mississippi":"MS"
    "Missouri":"MO"
    "Montana":"MT"
    "Nebraska":"NE"
    "Nevada":"NV"
    "New Hampshire":"NH"
    "New Jersey":"NJ"
    "New Mexico":"NM"
    "New York":"NY"
    "North Carolina":"NC"
    "North Dakota":"ND"
    "Ohio":"OH"
    "Oklahoma":"OK"
    "Oregon":"OR"
    "Pennsylvania":"PA"
    "Rhode Island":"RI"
    "South Carolina":"SC"
    "South Dakota":"SD"
    "Tennessee":"TN"
    "Texas":"TX"
    "Utah":"UT"
    "Vermont":"VT"
    "Virginia":"VA"
    "Washington":"WA"
    "West Virginia":"WV"
    "Wisconsin":"WI"
    "Wyoming":"WY"
    return us_state_abbrev[cd]

df['STATE_CD'] = df.Names.apply(lambda x:convert_state_name(x))
```

Finally you can replace locations=df['Names'] with locations=df['STATE_CD']

Hope this helps.